# IPhone and Xcode keychain - Can't delete keychain?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, keychain

I have an app that writes to the keychain via KeyChainWrapper to validate an in-app purchase. Everything is working OK except that I can't seem to be able to delete the keychain item. I can delete when running through XCode, however, when I download the app from the App Store, do an actual in-app purchase, the keychain does not get deleted when I run my reset code in my app. I take it that there are two different keychain items installed on the device, one from the actual in-app purchases and one from the sandbox mode. I want to delete the keychain so when I download from the app store my app is back to normal without in-app purchase. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find anything on this ? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: testing MKStoreKit on the device (as it doesn't work in iOS sim), purchased my test feature and now it's stored somewhere in keychain on the device, I don't even know where - MKStoreKit does this automatically.

Removing the app from the device doesn't work. I don't think that the only way is to reset the device...